# auth is not a function

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to do a simple login form, and Firebase auth give me this error

> TypeError: *firebase__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1*_["default"].auth is
> not a function. (In
> '*firebase__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1*_["default"].auth()',
> '*firebase__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1*_["default"].auth' is undefined)

Somebody have the solution?

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from "react"
import app from '../firebase'

export const AuthContext = React.createContext();

export const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        app.auth().onAuthStateChanged(setCurrentUser);
       }, []);

       return (
           <AuthContext.Provider value={{currentUser}}>
               {children}
           </AuthContext.Provider>
       )
}
```

Comment: Probably firebase isn't imported. Check this tutorial https://blog.logrocket.com/user-authentication-firebase-react-apps/

Comment: What versions of the Firebase SDKs are you using?

Answer (score 0):

`const useAuth = () => useContext(AuthContext);`

`export { useAuth, AuthProvider };`

add these two lines at the end also